# Edit, Save and Delete button in Angular ag-Grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I want to add Edit/Save and Delete button in every row of ag-Grid(Angular version). I'm using community edition.

Clicking on Edit button should make entire row editable and show Save button. Delete button should remove the row.

Saw few answers on stackoverlow but seems they aren't working. Please help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create extra fields with no field data, and add buttons there. You can add the button using a `cellRenderer`. Then when each of your button's are clicked, you can call a method to do your desired action, e.g. save row, delete row etc.

I've created a quick example for you on StackBlitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world-bq5yev).

Comment: Can I add a pencil icon in place of edit button? If yes then how?